# Using vRaptor 3 with Tomcat UnpackWARs property setted to false

Tags: java, model-view-controller, tomcat, servlets, vraptor

I have to deploy my web app to a tomcat container with the `unpackWARs` property defined to `false`.
When I do that, although the application  is successfully deployed, when I try to access my url I always got a **404 error**. I just don't receive that error when I try to access a direct file like index.html for instance.
But I can't do that, the vRaptor framework is responsible for routing my url to the `jsp` file.

Does anyone know if I have do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add a configuration to my web.xml file like this:

```
<context-param>  
    <param-name>br.com.caelum.vraptor.packages</param-name>  
    <param-value>the.name.of.my.package</param-value>  
</context-param>
```